# HTML File Input - Set allowed extensions and event for selected file

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a file input field have the following extensions only "*.zip,*.rar,*.tar,*.tar.gz" and i also want to trap event for when file has been selected and dialog has closed. any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting the file selection to certain extensions can't be done using the normal browser's file upload control. You'd have to use a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) (Features Demo [here](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/featuresdemo/index.php)) or Uploadify for this.

The event of a new file selection will be reflected in the `onchange` event.